# Hofstadter male-female sequences in Forth

Tags: sequence, forth

I am trying to write a [Hofstadter sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence#Hofstadter_Female_and_Male_sequences) in Forth, without the use of recursion. I feel like I am very close, but I keep getting an error that is telling me,

> TypeError: x[m[w]] is not a function

when I run it with `10 MALE`. How can I fix this error?

My code is as follows:

```
VARIABLE SIZE
VARIABLE MALE-ARR
VARIABLE FEMALE-ARR

: MALE
    DUP SIZE !
    CREATE MALE-ARR SIZE @ CELLS ALLOT \ CREATE MALE ARRAY OF LENGTH N
    CREATE FEMALE-ARR SIZE @ CELLS ALLOT \ CREATE FEMALE ARRAY OF LENGTH N
    0 MALE-ARR ! \ MALE-ARR(0) = 0
    1 FEMALE-ARR ! \ FEMALE-ARR(0) = 1
    SIZE @ 1 DO
        i FEMALE-ARR MALE-ARR i 1- CELLS + @ CELLS + @ - MALE-ARR i CELLS + !
        i MALE-ARR FEMALE-ARR i 1- CELLS + @ CELLS + @ - FEMALE-ARR i CELLS + !
    LOOP
    SIZE @ 0 DO
        MALE-ARR i CELLS + @ .
    LOOP
    ;
```

Comment: What Forth are you using?  Also, the CREATEs in your code are clearly confused. Those would parse a name when MALE is run, but you don't supply such names.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
: array ( u "name" -- )   create cells allot  does> swap cells + ;

10 constant size
size array male
size array female

: compute ( -- )   0 0 male !  1 0 female !                                     
   size 1 do                                                                    
      i i 1- female @ male @ - i female !                                       
      i i 1- male @ female @ - i male !                                         
   loop ;

: print ( u -- )   0 do i male @ . loop ;
```